# How do I batch merge 2 images in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have lots of designs that I want to put on an image of a blank t-shirt.

Here the steps:

1. Open T-Shirt image
2. Open design image onto another layer
3. Reduce design image to about 40-50%
4. Position design image to centre on horizontal and about 33% down on vertical.
5. Save image as a new file
6. Go back to step one for next image

Is this possible with actions and batching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible if all the t-shirt images and all the design images are the same size.

The following instructions are for Photoshop CS4:

Click Window >> Actions.

At the bottom of the Actions window click the Create New Action button.  Name it "Merge Designs" or whatever you like.

Click Record and merge one design into one t-shirt.  This will presumably involve File >> Open on the t-shirt image, then however you would normally proceed (open, resize, position, etc.).

On the Actions window, click the Stop button (the square).

Click File >> Automate >> Batch.

In the Play section, from whatever Set you stored your action in, select the action.  For Source, choose your folder of T-shirt designs.  For Destination, pick a new (empty) folder.

Click OK.

I haven't actually tried this, you might have to fiddle with the actions.  In particular, I would suggest that having the t-shirt image in the clipboard before starting and simply pasting it will greatly simplify your job (since you will presumably only run this batch once).

Hope that's helpful.