# Batch process in photoshop, Merging two images together

Tags: batch, adobe-photoshop

this is more of a added question to an original question asked from this link.
[How do I batch merge 2 images in Photoshop?](https://superuser.com/questions/198295/how-do-i-batch-merge-2-images-in-photoshop)

im trying to accomplish this same feat, but i want to save as jpeg instead of psd
and is it possible to name the new file from the foreground image file name?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Load the foreground image first - this will keep the name, but will also **SAVE OVER IT** if you don't change the name.
2. When saving, change the file type to JPG.

Comment: hi hannu, thank you very much for your reply. I tried loading the foreground image first, but the batched file names still comes out as "file0001.psd", "file0002.psd" and so on.